# Apache Kafka console Producer-Consumer example

Tags: apache-kafka

I have installed Apache Kafka to a Windows system and have tried a console Producer-Consumer example. In case I add new consumers to the topic, only the messages after adding the consumer are printed to the console. Is there any way to get all the messages of the particular topic?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add **--from-beginning** flag to your console consumer command to get all messages.

Example command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```